# Outputing multiple .png graphs in Matplotlib to one zip file in Python 3.4

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a program that outputs multiple different pie charts (more than 60) from a CSV file using MatPlotLib in Python. I don't think I need to share all of the code, but I have a `draw()` function that creates the graph, that ends with the following:

```
def draw(data):
    [make the graph]
    plt.savefig(filename)
```

This function successfully makes one of my graphs as a .png file in the cwd. I then run a loop that creates a pie chart for each section of my data. The code is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = sys.argv[1]
    things = process(data) 
    for thing in things.values():
        draw(thing)
```

I'm wondering if there are any Python packages that would help me automatically output all 60+ graphs to one zip file.

Comment: Seems like it should be pretty straightforward with this module:  https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 5):

Sure, there's the standard [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module, which can zip existing files, and it can also zip a string of bytes. So if you don't want to create the files separately and then zip them you could save them to [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) objects and then zip up those byte buffers. I've linked you to the Python 3 docs, but those features are also available in Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save both `png`'s and the `zip`, maybe for debugging purposes, you can do something like using [`zipfile`](http://pymotw.com/2/zipfile/):

```
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('myzip.zip', mode='w')

zf.write('image1.png')
zf.write('image2.png')
# ...

zf.close()
```